# How to find $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, factoring

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2}$$

I know the answer of the left hand limit is $1/2$; while the right hand limit is $-1/2$. But I don't understand how do you get that?

If I factor $-x$ from the denominator, I'll get $(-2+x)$ which cancels out with the numerator. Then I'll get $1/-x$. If I plug in the limit of $2$ from the left hand, it would be $1/2$. Wouldn't it also be $1/2$ from the right hand, as well? I'm getting confused on how to work this out. Please help, thank you!

Comment: A graph may be very helpful

Comment: It doesn't cancel with the nunerator, $|x-2|=x-2$ only when $x\geq 2$ and $|x-2|=2-x$ otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to consider separately the two cases

- $x>2$ that is $x \to 2^+$ we have $|x-2|=x-2$ and thereofore

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2}=\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{x-2}{x(2-x)}=\lim_{x\to 2^+}-\frac{1}{x}$$

- $x<2$ that is $x \to 2^-$ we have $|x-2|=-x+2$ and thereofore

$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2}=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{-x+2}{x(2-x)}=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand most of it now but I just don't get how did |x−2|=−x+2  for the x<2? Is it because we're approaching 2 from the left?

Comment: @bluegreenocean Yes when $x<2$ we have $x-2<0$ and then $|x-2|=2-x>0$

Comment: Perfect, I got it. One last thing, for x>2, how did x-2 (numerator) cancel out with 2-x (denominator) when they're not the same? Shouldn't x-2 only be able to cancel out with x-2, not 2-x?

Comment: @bluegreenocean We have $\frac{x-2}{2-x}=-1\cdot \frac{2-x}{2-x}=-1$.

Answer (score 4):

You might find it easier to analyze with the substitution $u = x-2$. Then it becomes

$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{|u|}{-u(u+2)}=\lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{-1}{u+2}\frac{|u|}{u}=\left(\lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{-1}{u+2}\right)\left( \lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{|u|}{u}\right)=\frac {-1}2 \left(\lim_{u \rightarrow 0}\frac{|u|}{u}\right) $

$\frac{|u|}u$ is just $sign(u)$: it's $-1$ for $u<0$ and $1$ for $u>0$.

Answer (score 3):

first:
if $f(x) = \frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2}$
then :
$\lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{x-2}{x\cdot (2-x)} = \lim_{x \to 2^+} -\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{2}$
and
$\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{2-x}{x\cdot (2-x)} = \lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$
but from the definition we have $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) =l \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) =l$ but $\frac{1}{2} \neq -\frac{1}{2}$ thus limit of $f(x)$ at $x=2$ does not exist.

Comment: If you type `$\lim$`, you will obtain $\lim$.

Answer (score 0):

Piece-wise definition of a modulus states that
whenever
$$ a>0 => |a| = a$$
And $$a<0 => |a| = -a$$
Because the modulus of anything should be positive.
If taking limit from LHS, $$\lim_{x\to 2^-} x<2 => x-2<0 => |x-2|= -(x-2)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{|x-2|}{2x-x^2} = \frac{-(x-2)}{x(2-x)}= \frac{1}{2}$$
Similarly if $$x>2=>x-2>0 => |x-2| = x-2$$
Therefore the limit is  negative half.